# how to add multiple directories in classpath in process builder using java

Tags: java, terminal, command, classpath, processbuilder

i want to add multiple directory in classpath . i have two directories `/user/WEB-INF/lib` , `/user/WEB-INF/thirdpartyLib`.In processbuilder while constructing command

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList();
  command.add("java");
  command.add("-cp");
  command.add(
 "user/WEB-INF/thirdpartyLib/*"+":"+
 "user/WEB-INF/lib/*"+":."  );
 command.add("com.test.process.Test1"); 
Process process=  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/sh", "-c", String.join(" ", command) });
```

Test1 class has dependency in thirdpartyLib which is present in user/WEB-INF/thirdpartyLib directories. while running it giving error

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.
```

but same
command (`java -cp /user/WEB-INF/thirdpartyLib/*:/user/WEB-INF/lib/*:. com.test.process.Test1`)i am running in terminal its working fine. please help me. Thanks in advance.`

Comment: ```"user/WEB-INF/..."``` -> ```"/user/WEB-INF/..."``` ?

Comment: @英語は苦手sorry i did not get you

Comment: They mean try to make the path absolute (notice the leading `/` in the new version) and see if that works. You have that leading `/` in your "same command I am running in terminal", by the way.